# Visual C# best button adding solution

Tags: c#, button

I use this solution(in code below) to add multiply buttons on panel. It works ok but it takes too long, when it tries to add a lot of buttons (for an example 40). I want to ask, if any one knows of a better solution for this situation? I was thinking of creating all possible buttons at program start-up, but in this case will start-up take too long, especially if there will be really lot of buttons (this scenario is possible)?

```
while (data.Read())
{
  btnName = Convert.ToString(data["Name"]);
  btnColor = (color == string.Empty) ? Convert.ToString(data["Color"]) : color;
  categoryId = Convert.ToInt16(data["CategoryId"]); 
  //both category and article table's contains this data!

  if (categoryId == articleCatId || cl == typeof(Category))
  {
      Button newbtn = new Button();
      newbtn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
      newbtn.Click += (sender, e) => method(sender, e);
      newbtn.Text = btnName;
      newbtn.Name = "button-" + btnName;
      newbtn.Height = size;
      newbtn.Width = size;
      newbtn.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", fontH);
      newbtn.Location = new Point(paddingL, paddingT);
      newbtn.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(btnColor);
      location.Controls.Add(newbtn);
      num += 1;

      if ((num - 1) / inline == 1) { paddingT += size; paddingL = 2; num = 1; }
      else { paddingL = paddingL + size; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to enclose the code with SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout, it will prevent multiple redraws of the form.

Comment: *"when it tries to add a lot of buttons (for an example 40)"* - And, when you type that sentence, you should stop to think; *"why in the world am I adding **40 buttons** to a form?!"*  No one wants to look at 40 buttons.  It's not usable.  Think of a better solution or tell us what you are actually trying to achieve so that we can suggest one.

Comment: Don't add 40 buttons to a single form, I'd start with that ;)

Comment: `I want to ask, if any one knows of a better solution for this situation?` - Yes of course, forget crappy winforms and use any of the current (< 10 years old), hardware-accelerated, vector-based, much more performant and more scalable, and actually easier to code against, XAML-based technologies (such as WPF or WinRT). I can create literally 10k controls in a window and it takes less than a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cannot reduce the number of buttons you need to create, so you then have some options to speed it up a little bit:

1. Add the buttons to an object that is not visible. Only when you're done adding buttons, you make the object visible.
2. Call [`SuspendLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) on the parent control to stop it from trying to layout itself. Then call [`ResumeLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout.aspx) when you're done adding buttons.
3. Use a more lightweight control than a button, that is more appropriate for the task. For example a `Listbox`, `Combobox`, or several checkboxes or option buttons styled as normal buttons.
4. Write your own lightweight `Button` control that does exactly what you want but no more.